Equality of the $L^1$ norm and measure norm of an corresponding absolutely continuous measure for BV functions
Let $u \in BV(I;\mathbb{R}^d)$ be a vector valued function of bounded variation, (in particular Bochner integrable) on an open interval $I \subset \mathbb{R}$. We can then define the Radon measure
$u \cdot \mathcal{L} \in \mathcal{M}(I;\mathbb{R}^d)$
$$
 u \cdot \mathcal{L} (A) := \int_A u dx
$$
for all measurable $A$. My question is does the following equality holds?
$$
\|u \|_{L^1} = \| u \cdot \mathcal{L} \|_M
$$
The direction "$\geq$" can be directly archieved by definition of the $L^1$-norm and Jensen inequality for the Bochner integral, but I am not sure about the other direction. For smooth functions, the equality holds, as shown in this paper by Ambrosio and Dal Maso (equation 1.2). Is this true for general Bochner integrable functions or BV functions? My intuition says it can be shown with the fundamental theorem of calculus for 1d BV functions.

For '$\leq$', one can use density of continuous functions in $L^1$ and the result is even true when we take an arbitrary Radon measure $\mu$ instead of the Lebesgue measure and taking $u \in L^1(\Omega, \mu; \mathbb{R}^d)$ where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ open and bounded. Then the mapping
$$
u\mu : \mathscr{B}(\Omega ) \to \mathbb{R}^d, \quad u\mu(B) := \int_B ud\mu
$$
defines a vector valued Radon measure and $\|u\|_{L^1} = \|u\mu\|_M$. Indeed
$$
\begin{split}
\|u\|_{L^1} &= \int_\Omega |u|d\mu = \int_\Omega \left(u,\frac{u}{|u|}\right) d\mu \\
&\leq \sup_{\substack{\varphi \in \mathcal{C}_0(\Omega, \mathbb{R}^d) \\ \|\varphi \|_C = 1}} \langle\varphi, u\mu \rangle
\end{split}
$$
by density of $C_c(\Omega, \mathbb{R}^d)$ in $L^1(\Omega, \mu; \mathbb{R}^d)$ and dominated convergence. Conversely with the definition of total variation and Jensen inequality for Bochner integrals, the total variation measures satisfy $|u\mu| \leq |u|\mu$ and together with Riesz representation theorem we get
\begin{equation*}
\|u\mu\|_M = |u\mu|(\Omega) \leq |u|\mu(\Omega) = \|u\|_{L^1}.
\end{equation*}
